# How to read and then forward an MJPEG camera stream using embedded programming

Tags: ip-camera

I am trying to read and then forward an MJPEG stream using embedded programming.
I am using an WiFi based ARM chipset from Texas Instruments. I am trying to read from an IP camera using http requests but I am not receving any response from the camera. My receive is failing with code:TRY AGAIN.
I also tried to send the http request to the camera using a DHC based REST client but the DHC just says "Sending" and there is not response.

Can someone please clarify?

regards,
Rajkumar

Answer (score 0):

did you see server receive request?
if not,check if network is working between server and client exactly

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I was doing a receive on the wrong socket. The issue is resolved now.